# How many rows is a JTable currently displaying?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

JTable has a method getVisibleRowCount(), which shows the *preferred* number of rows to display.

I want to determine the *actual* number of rows currently visible in a JTable. How can I do this?

My current attempt is:

```
int rowsVisible = table.getSize().getHeight()/table.getRowHeight();
```

but the value it gives me is quite higher than what I can see.

For example, when there are 10 or 11 rows visible, this gives me a result of 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I would expect when a `JTable` is contained in a `JScrollPane`, you can ask the scrollpane for its viewport using `getViewPort`, and retrieve the size from the viewport.

If you divide that height with the row height of the table, you might get a better estimation

```
final int pageSize = 
    (int) (table.getParent().getSize().getHeight() / table.getRowHeight());
```

is pretty close

Comment: sorry ... but a) incomplete (as @Mikle Garin already noted) and far too low-level (always use the highest abstraction available, as you well know ;-)

Comment: @SteveMcLeod There are far better answers in this thread. If you unaccepted this answer I can delete this, as it is not correct

Answer (score 11):

Ask the table, it's doing all the hard work for you:

```
Rectangle vr = table.getVisibleRect ();
int first = table.rowAtPoint(vr.getLocation());
vr.translate(0, vr.height);
int visibleRows = table.rowAtPoint(vr.getLocation()) - first;
```

Comment: `getVisibleRect` ... I knew there was a method in `JTable` but my search on *view* did not gave any good results. An upvote for this answer, and need to check whether I can delete my accepted one

Comment: In my case it didn't work as I was modifying the `TableModel` just before and I still had the old table visible row count. Since I was more interested in the **possible visible row count**, I changed the code to `Rectangle vr = table.getParent() instanceof JViewport ? ((JViewport) table.getParent()).getViewRect() : table.getVisibleRect();`

Answer (score 1):

Exactly none of these attempts is correct. Simply since its don't care about scrolling down... :-/

I wrote the code based on the correct answers which I was able to find, which was tried and was correct (I hope).

But i tried it only for column 0...

```
public static int getNumberOfVisibleRows(JTable table) {
    Rectangle vr = table.getVisibleRect();
    int first = table.rowAtPoint(vr.getLocation());
    vr.translate(0, vr.height);
    return table.rowAtPoint(vr.getLocation()) - first;
}

public static void scrollToVisible(JTable table, int rowIndex, int columnIndex, int numberOfVisibleRows) {
    Rectangle visibleRect = table.getVisibleRect();
    Rectangle rect1 = table.getCellRect(rowIndex, columnIndex, false);
    if (visibleRect.y > rect1.y) {
        table.scrollRectToVisible(rect1);
    } else {
        Rectangle rect2 = table.getCellRect(rowIndex + numberOfVisibleRows, columnIndex, false);
        int width = rect2.y - rect1.y;
        table.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(rect1.x, rect1.y, rect1.width, rect1.height + width));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way **Robin** offered is not fully correct - it won't work when table have different row heights. Also it doesn't check the rows spacing and some other small nuances.

Here is the example that will work with any L&F and table settings:

```
public static void main ( String args[] )
{
    final JLabel rows = new JLabel ( "Visible rows: ?", JLabel.CENTER );

    final JTable table = new JTable ( new DefaultTableModel ( 30, 3 )
    {
        public String getColumnName ( int column )
        {
            return "title";
        }

        public Object getValueAt ( int row, int column )
        {
            return "cell";
        }
    } );

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane ( table )
    {
        public Dimension getPreferredSize ()
        {
            Dimension ps = super.getPreferredSize ();
            ps.height = 150;
            return ps;
        }
    };
    scroll.addComponentListener ( new ComponentAdapter ()
    {
        public void componentResized ( ComponentEvent e )
        {
            Rectangle vr = table.getVisibleRect ();
            int visibleRows = 0;
            for ( int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount (); i++ )
            {
                Rectangle cell = table.getCellRect ( i, 0, false );
                if ( cell.y <= vr.y && cell.y + cell.height >= vr.y ||
                        cell.y <= vr.y + vr.height &&
                                cell.y + cell.height >= vr.y + vr.height ||
                        cell.y >= vr.y && cell.y + cell.height <= vr.y + vr.height )
                {
                    visibleRows++;
                }
            }
            rows.setText ( "Visible rows: " + visibleRows );
        }
    } );

    JPanel panel = new JPanel ( new BorderLayout ( 25, 25 ) );
    panel.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( 25, 25, 25, 25 ) );
    panel.add ( rows, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    panel.add ( scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
    frame.add ( panel );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack ();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
    frame.setVisible ( true );
}
```

Just try resizing the table to see the effect.

Also you can modify the "is cell visible" condition to exclude (as an example) rows that have less that 5 pixels (or half of their height) visible.

Comment: near .. but still too low-level (no need to loop, just ask the table :-)

Comment: @kleopatra You will have to loop, if you want to exclude cells which has only a few visible pixels or if you are using some complex tables (like the ones from the Jide package) properly. For example - some tree table with some rows collapsed, in that case your aproach won't work ;)

Comment: it must - if it doesn't the table implementation is buggy ;-) Don't see any reason to want to exclude rows below a given height - either you want the actual count or not.

Comment: @kleopatra in case with tree table (or some other similar table-like structures) you can get hidden rows between visible rows. That means when you get lastVisibleRow-firstVisibleRow value it might be larger than actual visible rows amount. That was my point. But in general - yes, your approach will work faster and takes less effort.

Comment: repeating myself: if the jide treetable counts the collapsed (aka: hidden rows) then its implementation is wrong: the returned rowIndex _must be_ in view coordinates and those _must be_ contiguous. Now running to check if our JXTreeTable is well-behaved :-)

Comment: Might be that. In that case its true that you can always rely on rows

Answer (score -4):

Try:

```
table.getModel().getRowCount();
```

Comment: that returns the total # of rows in the table, and not the # of rows currently visible.

Comment: sorry my bad. it probably has something to do with the JScrollPane.

Comment: Voting to delete this answer as it doesn't answer the question being asked.