# How to get all visible rows of JTable model within a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jviewport

So far I know how to get a particular row at a point using the JScrollPane's JViewPort object.

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
            Point p = viewport.getViewPosition();
            int rowIndex = getLogsTable().rowAtPoint(p);
            System.out.println("Minimum Y: " + viewport.getViewRect().getMinY());
            System.out.println("Min row: " + getLogsTable().rowAtPoint(new Point(0, (int) viewport.getViewRect().getMinY())));
            System.out.println("Maximum Y: " + viewport.getViewRect().getMaxY());
            System.out.println("Max row: " + getLogsTable().rowAtPoint(new Point(0, (int) viewport.getViewRect().getMaxY())));
        }

    });
```

I am having a tough time figuring out how to get all the rows between the JViewport.getMinimumY() and JViewport.getMaximumY(). Is there a way to gather all row items between those two viewport points or is there any way to just get all rows in the JScrollPane view?

Comment: If you want to get the table's visible row count see @kleopatra's answer in this thread: [How many rows is a JTable currently displaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887642/how-many-rows-is-a-jtable-currently-displaying). If you want to get a list of all rows that are visible, that answer will help you too.

Comment: So, should I use the row count to loop through row indeces?

Comment: No, simply getting the first and last rows would be enough. What is in the middle is calculable. For isntance: first row is `3` and last row is `7`, then you have `{3,4,5,6,7}`.

Comment: Suspecting an [*XY problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I ask: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: Table of arbitrary model supplies another area of the GUI I am developing with optional data from that model. Since the table could potentially have 1000s of rows, I do not all of it to be supplied to the other area. Only the data from the visible rows, and the other area will be updated as user scrolls through the table.

Comment: @dic19 if you can change your comment to an answer, I'd be willing to set is as the accepted answer. I used the rudiments of kleopatra's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @dic19's comment, I used that snippet of code, and it worked. I just added an extra variable to handle retrieving the last row index number.

```
// need to wait for table to fully load
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // getLogsTable() returns JTable instance
            Rectangle vr = getLogsTable().getVisibleRect();
            int firstRow = getLogsTable().rowAtPoint(vr.getLocation());
            vr.translate(0, vr.height);
            int visibleRows = getLogsTable().rowAtPoint(vr.getLocation()) - firstRow;
            int lastRow = (visibleRows > 0) ? visibleRows+firstRow : getLogsTable().getRowCount();

            System.out.println("first visible row: " + firstRow + " last visible row: " + lastRow);

            for(int rowNum=firstRow+1; rowNum<=lastRow; rowNum++) {
                    // LogsModel is a AbstractTableModel instance
                    LogsModel model = (LogsModel) getLogsTable().getModel();
                    Log log = model.getData().get(getLogsTable().convertRowIndexToModel(rowNum-1));
                    System.out.println(log.getLocation());
            }

            System.out.println(lastRow);
        }

    });
```

Comment: +1 because you did solve your problem on your own and you wisely use [JTable#convertRowIndexToModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-). Keep in that way!